# How to change timestamp of data change in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking to make a timestamp update of when any particular fields are updated in my Ruby on Rails app.

I have a `"dprojects"` table that has a column for `"status"` and `"status_date"`.

How can I make it so that if/when the status is updated, the `status_date` also changes to be the date the status that was most recently updated to?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of ActiveRecord's dirty attribute tracking to set the status date if the status column was changed. Use a before_save callback and then set the status date if needed:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_status_date

  def set_status_date
    self.status_date = Time.now if status_changed?
  end
end
```